# "Incorrect table definition" when trying to CREATE TABLE

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a table in a php script  and I am getting an SQL error. I can't find it or figure out how to fix it. I do have $table defined earlier in the script. Thanks in advance!

```
$newtable = "CREATE TABLE $table (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, time datetime NOT NULL,punchtype VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,groupname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, dept VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, notes VARCHAR(255))";
```

Error Message: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it works

```
$newtable = "CREATE TABLE $table
(id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
time datetime NOT NULL,
punchtype VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
groupname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
dept VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
notes VARCHAR(255))";
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out not 5 seconds before I came to check this page for an answer and update it. I forget to put a primary key in the query. Thank you guys!

Comment: You can leave out `NOT NULL` on `AUTO_INCREMENT`, as well. It's implicit. Also, you might want to define your `ENGINE`. Just a comment.